# I want index.php should be hide in the Website's URL

Tags: 14.04

I hosted PHP Website on UBUNTU 14.04 and it is working good.
But I want index.php should be hide in Website's URL.
How should I do, Could anyone please help me how to do it ?

Thank You.

Comment: A rewrite rule should be in order!

Comment: Please give example of the current url and what you want to appear!

Comment: @Manohar do you want to hide ".php" extension?

Comment: Yes I want to hide ".pho" extension in URl. How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set `DirectoryIndex` directive in Apache config or in local *.htaccess*.

Standard installation of apache2 on 16.04 LTS has the following

file */etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf* contains

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
```

This will hide *index.php* from URL (you will see *http://servername/dir/* instead of *http://servername/dir/index.php*).

In addition you may add the following lines to the *.htaccess* file

```
RewriteEngine on
# index.php -> /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://servername/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This example will redirect *http://servername/index.php* to *http://servername/*.

Comment: from your first part setting " DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm " setting this in dir.conf will hide ".php" extension?

Comment: Yes. On default apache2 installation web server has only */var/www/html/index.html* which is accessed by `http://localhost` (no *index.html* in the end). If we remove this file and palce *index.php* here it will be accessed as `http://localhost`. But this first part does not block `http://localhost/index.php` direct access. So the second part is needed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have used, you can add `.htaccess` in your root directory. And then add following content into it:

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

After that you can name your links without `.php` extension.
Eg if there was a link to `Home` with `index.php` as shown below:

**Before:**

`<li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>`

**After**  saving `.htaccess` use can use it like this without `.php` extension.

`<li><a href="../index">Home</a></li>`

Maybe there is a better way to do it but right now this is how I do it. (I am new to php pardon me for my mistakes)

**NOTE :**  Files will be named with `.php` extension eg `about.php`, `contact.php`. But file names in `href` will be without `.php` extension.

[image]